# Power Point VBA - Copy Picture from Userform to Slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint, userform, shapes

Dear Fellow StackOverFlow-members,

is there a possibility to copy a picture from an userform into a slide?

I've tried several approaches:

`ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture`     'Filename has to be a string, thus i can't set the Userform as source

I've thought of something like  `frm_Userform.Image1.Picture` to get somehow the picture, but I have no idea to set the picture within a slide.

The possibilties to pre-define a picture path is not possible as several users with different user rights are going to use the makro (add-in).

Are there maybe other possibilities to save a picture within an add-in and use (paste) it on slides ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post your code. Perhaps you could back up and tell us what you're trying to accomplish. Is this supposed to be an alternate image picker? Why would a user be choosing a picture that's on a user form?

Comment: The users are going to receive an automatically created PowerPoint-Report. This Report is going to be created by an Excelmacro (can't be accessed). The report contains a list with a string column: "customer1", "customer2" and "customer3". After each string has to be put an image of the brand logo. Customers can appear several times. If I insert manually the logo and paste it by request it works properly, but want to skip the part of the manual paste process. Thus, I tried to save the logos within a userform as workaround.

Comment: Can you put the logo files in a known location? Then you can add them with something like:

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the logo files in a known location? Then you can add them with something like:

```
IconFile$ = AddinPath$ & "\YellowIcon.gif"
Set ShO = PresO.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=IconFile$, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=10, Height:=10)
With ShO
    .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
    .ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
End With
```

Comment: Solution is similar. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyFromUserFormToSlide

Const TempFolder = 2
Dim fso, path
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
path = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TempFolder).Path & "\" & fso.GetTempName
SavePicture UserForm.Image1.Picture, path
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture path,msoFalse,msoTrue,150,150
fso.DeleteFile path

End Sub
```

This did the job for me. Excel solution was on stack and had to adjust it to PowerPoint. Thank you anyway!